# Unresolved Reference : FragmentTitleBinding

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-databinding

I want to use fragments in my android application but I can't import `FragmentTitleBinding` in my fragment class I tried all possible solutions on the internet

1. I checked layout tags in xml file
2. I edit build.gradle file
3. sync project

```
import com.example.android.navigation.databinding.FragmentTitleBinding

class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding : com.example.android.navigation.databinding.FragmentTitleBinding=
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_title,container,false)
    return binding.root;
    }
}
```

*Fragment XML*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.android.navigation.TitleFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/playButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:text="Play"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleImage" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/titleImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_header_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/android_trivia" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

*build.gradle*

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.android.navigation'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // Kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$version_kotlin"
    // Constraint Layout
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$version_constraint_layout"
    // Core
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$version_core"
    // Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$version_material"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.3.0'
}
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I want to resolved `FragmentTitleBinding` but it gives an error unresolved reference

Comment: Please show your ```R.layout.fragment_title```.

Comment: @Tidder Please check now

Comment: Try to add a ```<data>``` tag to your layout file within the ```<layout>...</layout>``` tags like in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions.html

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since databinding perform like annotation processor, you have to clean your project then rebuild again. If that way not work. Try this:
1. Click file menu
2. Select Invalidate Caches/ Restart

[image]

I hope it works. And please aware that your databinding class has same name with your layout name

**Update**

Make sure you have these inside your dependencies

```
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
```

and

```
android{
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

also you need to check Repository in SDK tools
[image: sdk tools]

Comment: there is no type there? in this  dataBinding { enabled = true}?

Comment: actually in jetpack already include databinding ( kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0") you do not need this dependency anymore kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.3.0'

Comment: Finally It worked by rebuild project it didn't worked previously but now it works :)

Comment: Why do we need `kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:"`?

Comment: AFAIK, that's only needed if you have lifecycle-related annotations in your code, specifically @OnLifecycleEvent.

Comment: After invalidating cache my kotlin files are full of red lines and the project does not compile anymore :(

Comment: @jap1968 You have to connect to Internet after invalidate and restart, some missing library will rechecking out. Also make sure that you do not have gradle issues

Comment: Solved the problem with `Clean Project` + `Rebuild Project`

Comment: @NandaZ Do I need to install Support Repository in Android Studio 4.2?

Comment: @ide i recommend to do it. But, library might be changed. it must be independent now

Answer (score 2):

This problem was driving me nuts and the problem remained even after trying the above fixes.  And it’s tough because if you are reading this blog it is most likely you are working your way through the ‘Android Kotlin Fundamentals 03.1: Create a fragment’ online course.  The last thing you need is an unexplained bug when you are learning.

In my case the fault was that the IDE added ‘import android.R’ at the top of the import stack.  Remove that import code and the problem goes away.

In Android Studio there is an informational message that is associated with the problematic ‘import android.R’ code which reads;

*Don't include android.R here; use a fully qualified name for each usage instead*

*Inspection info: Importing android.R is usually not intentional; it sometimes happens when you use an IDE and ask it to automatically add imports at a time when your project's R class is not present.
Once the import is there you might get a lot of "confusing" error messages because of course the fields available on android.R are not the ones you'd expect from just looking at your own R class.*

*Issue id: Suspiciousimport*

I hope this helps other learners like myself

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent an hour pulling my hair, wondering why I kept getting "Unresolved reference"!

Answer (score 1):

Usually when we create the fragment_title, the default file created is ->[image]

so try to change the  to  and then the FragmentTitleBinding error can be avoided.
[image]

Comment: do let me know if you face any issue on that or not

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in **android in build.gradle(app)**

```
buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
```

Here are following options, you can try.
After creating blank TitleFragment.kt, Go to fragment_title.xml, replace it by

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.testfragment.TitleFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <!-- your xml tag-->

        

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Now go to **Build -> Clean project**, **Build -> Rebuild Project**. If you still get error, then **File -> Invalidate caches/restart**.

You can also look at this thread.
https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-android-trivia/issues/9